# MVC Create Controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework. Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

So, i am trying to learn how to use MVC Framework.
I used this link as tutorial to pick this framework up:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/adding-a-view

I have problem on creating the controller for my Model which named Movie, I encountered an error which i cannot solve when i have reached step "Accessing your model data from controller (C#)"

Every time i try to create a controller like the instructions told me to i received this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbhAC.png)

I am still newbie here so i don;t really know what to do,
I have tried to change the providerName in Web.config to the same as the 2nd connectionStrings but same error keeps appearing, my Model code looks exactly the same as the link i provided

Movie.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    [Table("Movies")]
    public class Movie
    {
        [Key]
        public int movieid { get; set; }

        public string movie_title { get; set; }
        public DateTime release_date { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public decimal ticket_price { get; set; }
    }
    public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Portion of my Web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MovieDBContext"
         connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Movies.sdf"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication1-20170909114325.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication1-20170909114325;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Please include your Movie class code.

Comment: done, Movie.cs Added

Comment: In case the linked answer doesn't help you, change movie_id to MovieId or Id or add [Key] directly above movie_id.

Comment: Yeah, i have already edited my code  just like the linked answer's
and changed movie_id to movieid, but the error still show up when i am trying to create new controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error describes about the Movie entity having no keys defined.

Have you updated the schema of the Movies table as shown in the instruction?

[image]